# enable History in ScriptManager in dnn module?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-6

just I wan to ask how can I Enable history in ScriptManager  Dnn  module I tryied this  `DotNetNuke.Framework.AJAX.SetScriptManagerProperty` and it only work with DNN 5.4 
just how can I do it in DNN 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it you can use this code

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
```